# android: lock view at bottom of page under listview

Tags: android

I am trying to have a locked position linear layout within a relative layout.

There should be a listview and at the botoom of the page a linear layout with 2 checkboxes.
The problem is that the last item in the listview can never be seen as it is hiding under the linearlayout.

Help appreciated!

**My layout xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/choose_children_lv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:dividerHeight="5dip"
            android:divider="@color/light_gray"
            android:padding="5dip">
        </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip">
        <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/childCheckAllTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/check_all" />
        <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/childUncheckAllTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/uncheck_all" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add id to linearlayout and make your listview "above" linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/choose_children_lv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:dividerHeight="5dip"
            **android:above="@+id/mywrapper"**
            android:divider="@color/light_gray"
            android:padding="5dip">
        </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        **android:id="@+id/mywrapper"**
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip">
        <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/childCheckAllTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/check_all" />
        <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/childUncheckAllTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/uncheck_all" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```